# List Azure table value

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have one question, which could be pretty dumb but I spent almost a week on it. I want to create Azure Function with http trigger which will check that URL which request comes is in Azure table and if such url exists, it will redirect it to another url, which will be e.g. 3 values in a given db record. The redirection process and the process of retrieving data from the database when the record matches I have working, the only problem is how to get a specific value from a given line.
How to get the value of the properties? Converting 'data' to a list doesn't work.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Environment;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class Redirect2
    {
        [FunctionName("Redirect2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "todo")] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("tablename", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudTable cloudTable,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string OriginUrl = "test.domain.com";

        TableQuery<TodoTable> query = new TableQuery<TodoTable>().Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl),
        TableOperators.Or, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl)));  

        var segment =  cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(query);
        var data = segment.Select(TodoExtensions.ToTodo);

        return new OkObjectResult(data);

    }
    }

}

public class TodoTable : TableEntity
{
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public string wwwURL { get; set; } 

    public string ClientURL { get; set; }
}

public class Todo
{
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public string wwwURL { get; set; } 

    public string ClientURL { get; set; }
}

public static class TodoExtensions
{
    public static TodoTable ToTable(this Todo todo)
    {
        return new TodoTable
        {
            PartitionKey = todo.URL,
            RowKey = todo.wwwURL,
            ClientURL = todo.URL
        };
    }

    public static Todo ToTodo(this TodoTable todoTable)
    {
        return new Todo
        {
            URL = todoTable.PartitionKey,
            wwwURL = todoTable.RowKey,
            ClientURL = todoTable.URL
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect to have single match for url?

Comment: How you pass OriginUrl  to your service via url ?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat I will redirect url to app service using dns. Yes, if there is a record there will be only one. The logic will be more like this -> the url in the browser redirects to the address of the appservice, the function checks if the url is in the database -> if so, it redirects the user to the url which will be 3 values of this record

Comment: SO originUrl is domain which you will get from domain? req.Host.Value ?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat Yes, originurl will be original url, which we need to check that exists in db

Comment: Can you share how the data stored in an entity look like? Please edit your question and include that.

Comment: Its not that. Data from your storage explorer. Open table and show data pls

Comment: Which shows PartitionKey and RowKey as well please. Thanks.

Comment: Please include column headers ;)

Comment: SOmethind does not make sense in your screen there is no "test.domain.com";

Comment: @VovaBilyachat I updated screenshot and script - yes, test.ecovadis.com instead of test.domain.com. How to get only URL column value without partitionkey and rowkey? Is there any other way to retrieve these records so that they can be easily used in the code?

Comment: @GauravMantri added at the bottom once again, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up with partitions

```
 TableQuery<TodoTable> query = new TableQuery<TodoTable>().Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl),
    TableOperators.Or, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl)));
```

So here you try to match by rowKey or partitionKey this will be costly since it will need to go via all data in your Table Storage. What you really want to do is always query single partition.

So what I would recommend you to do is to set PartitionKey lets say just to "Default". Then you always query single partition.

If I understand you correctly to make your code work you should do smth like this

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "todo")]
        HttpRequest req,
        [Table("tablename", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
        CloudTable cloudTable,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string OriginUrl = req.Host.Value;

         TableQuery<TodoTable> query = new TableQuery<TodoTable>().Where(
            TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(nameof(TableEntity.PartitionKey), QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl),
                TableOperators.And,
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(nameof(TableEntity.RowKey), QueryComparisons.Equal, OriginUrl)))
            .Take(1);

        var segment = cloudTable.ExecuteQuery(query);
        var data = segment.Select(TodoExtensions.ToTodo).FirstOrDefault();

         return new OkObjectResult(new { url = data?.URL});

    }
```

Comment: as a result I get all 3 values (partitionkey, rowkey, URL), how to enumerate after them so as to extract only the one I am interested in - value only 3 columns? How to split 'data' variable?

Comment: Because you messed up with partition key. Can you add screenshot into your question with data? you probably have same partitionkey for all of them

Comment: @Kivas updated again from your data you can use TableOperators.And instead of or

Comment: I spent a week on something that only needed one little  '?'. For this moment it works, I hope when I put all the parts together - it will work as well. THANK YOU  @VovaBilyachat

Comment: @Kivas thats usually like that ;) those time consuming problems usually are very stupid mistakes this is why if i cant solve problem in 45 minutes i ask for help